# Duplicate embeddable objects inserted

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an `Entity` including a collection of `Embeddable` objects as follows:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "as")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<B> bs;

    public B getB(String name) {
        for(B b : bs)
            if(b.getName().equals(name))
                return b;
        return null;
    }

    public void addB(B b) {
        if(!bs.add(b))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate ......");
    }

    ....
}

@Embeddable
public class B {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date creationTimestamp;

}
```

I'm using Spring Data to load and save my entity as follows:

```
Optional<A> a = aRepository.findById(aId);

B b = a.getB(...);
if(b == null) {
    b = new B(...);
    a.addB(b);
}

aRepository.save(a);
```

The code above is in a method annotatted with `@Transactional`.

When the method returns, I can see 3 duplicate embeddable objects in my database instead of one.

Any idea?

---

**EDIT:**

After a long debugging, I can confirm that Hibernate only inserts only one row for the single instance I add. However, when I return the created object from my REST controller, at some point the Jackson object mapper is involved to serialize my object before sending it back to the client, and here happens the two remaining INSERTs... I never saw that before... any help would be appreciated

**More information:**

The last 2 INSERTs are done when the SessionRepository commits the sessions changes - I precise that I use Spring Session. If that can help...

Comment: I don’t know why you get duplicates but see that you have an inconsistency in what is meant by equal between the getB and the add method, in getB you use the name property but in add you check if it is the same object.

Comment: I don't think it's related. I can tell you that while debugging, juste after loading the instance of A, its embedded collection of Bs is empty. After adding an instance of A, this same emebedded collection only has one element, the newly added element. But I can't explain how I get 3 rows in the table.

Comment: It might not be related but to me it is an inconsistency since you allow to add multiple instances of b with the same name but only will return one of them when calling getB(...)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it looks like it is related but I don't have an explanation at this moment. Please see my last commend to Bejond's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue happens here `bs.add(b)`. `Set` adds an object would check if the object exists in the set. But in your case object `b` would always not the same as existing object because of `creationTimestamp`. `creationTimestamp` would be different from existing object. Because you new object, the time would be current datatime. So `bs.add(b)` would always be `true`.

Try to remove `creationTimestamp` and rerun your code to verify this.

You need to override equals() and hashCode() of B

Comment: I tried without the timestamps and indeed I only see one row now. However, your explanation makes no sense to me since my code is calling the add method once so there is no issue of the method add allowing adding duplicate by always returning true - with my execution, the add method is called only once. Are you saying there are internal Hibernate checks that rely on equals/hashcode?